# jQuery each function, skip a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use the jQuery each function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

I have a list of things, and I want to perform different javascript for different list elements.

Here's  the  html code:

```
<ul id="list-with-stuff">
    <li class='non-stuff'>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
jQuery.fn.stuffplaylist = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('non-stuff')) {
            alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("FALSE. Has not got non-stuff class");
            return false;
        };
    });
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list-with-stuff").stuffplaylist();
});
```

Check it out on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/73gB9/

The problem I am having is not being able to work out how to determine what list element is selected, and thus run different javascript. For example I want to run the "TRUE" alert for the first element in the list, however it only runs the "FALSE" alert in it's current state.

I know it must be possible, however I'm inexperienced with Javascript & jQuery and haven't been able to work out from searching the internet.

With the above code if you make `ul` have the class `'non-stuff'` then it does output the "TRUE" alert message, otherwise the "FALSE" alert pops up.

So if you know the best practice way of doing it then I am keen to hear your answer. Particularly if it helps me along with learning Javascript :-)

Thank you.

Comment: "how to determine what list element is selected", what do you mean by selected?

Comment: Oops sorry. The `each` function goes through all the elements in the object I've passed right? So by selected I meant the object currently being used by the loop.

Comment: `$(this)` is the object currently used in loop.

Comment: If you mean the text foo or bar, look at .innerHTML() or .innerText()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing up your `<ul>` and `<li>`s. You're close.

If you want the plugin to operate on `<ul>`, make this modification:

```
jQuery.fn.stuffplaylist = function() {

    return this.children('li').each(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('non-stuff')) {
            alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("FALSE. Has not got non-stuff class");
            return false;
        };
    });
};
```

And you can refine this further by cutting the elements you don't need out of the selection.

```
   jQuery.fn.stuffplaylist = function() {
        return this.children('li.non-stuff').each(function() {
                //$(this).text() -> 'foo'
                alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
                return true;
        });
    };
```

Comment: This optimization is useless because he wants to act on all elements, just differently on non-stuff elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
return this.each(function(i, element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('non-stuff') || !i) { // !i == 0 and 0 is first element
        alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("FALSE. Has not got non-stuff class");
        return false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it seems that you are cycling through an array, that contains only a list. Try doing it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list-with-stuff li").each(function(index, element){
        if ($(element).hasClass('non-stuff')) {
            alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("FALSE. Has not got non-stuff class");
            return false;
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify the selector so it looks at the children in this case.

```
return $('#list-with-stuff li').each(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('non-stuff')) {
        alert("TRUE. Has non-stuff class");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("FALSE. Has not got non-stuff class");
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: This ain't how you author plugins.

Comment: That's true, but as far as I can see, the OP is not trying to author a plugin.

Comment: Regardless, this piece of code doesn't solve the problem, if that's what @Stefan meant. The selector still matches only the list, not its children.

Comment: @Igor: He is. Perhaps you should look into the jQuery docs as to how to write plugins.

Comment: @Greg: That's clearly not the OP's intention, and name a single plugin that does that. I've written and used many, and almost all act generically on whatever you select. That's part of the benefit of writing code in plugin form - instead of writing dinky functions that accept IDs, you get the full power of CSS selectors at your disposal. I'm not quite sure you understand the problem domain.